# Find the one operand of a bitwise operation

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Please help me..

If `(7 & x)*(12 & x) = 84` . Find the value of `x` ?

Note : Here **`&`** is `bitwise` '`and`'  operator.

Can anyone please suggest for writing the code to solve this problem in Python ?

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem; basically if the bottom four bits (the four bits set in the overlap of `7` and `12`) of the number are set, then it will work. There is no single solution. It's true for any `x` such that `x & 0xf == 0xf`, or equivalently in mathematical description, for any `x` where `x` is congruent to 15 modulo 16.

Comment: Is it possible that in this equation for a definte value (at the place of 84 ) more than 1 values of x are existed?

Comment: Yes. Bitwise and is a lossy operation, so many input operands to the bitwise and are going to be masked down to the same input operand for the multiplication step.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

```py
x=2

while(((7 & x)*(12 & x) != 84) and (x<50)):
    x+=1
if((7 & x)*(12 & x) == 84) : print(x)
else: print("x not found")
```

Outputs:
`15`

(You can start with different `x` e.g. when starting with `x=-100` you will get `x=-97`)

Comment: So how to find the smallest value of x in a specific range (e.g. 1 < x < 50) for this particular answer?

Comment: I tweaked my answer - now it will exactly look for solution for 1<x<50.